# color changing in assembly tasm

Tags: assembly

i have a problem in displaying the colors on the screen the number of rows and column is not accurate . Here is what I've tried.

```
.model small
.stack
.data
mes db'ENTER ANY NUMBER: $'
COUNTER DB '0'

.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

TYPEAGAIN:
mov ah,02H
MOV bh,00
mov dh,13
mov dl,35
int 10h

mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset mes
int 21h

mov ah,01h
int 21h
INC COUNTER

CMP AL,'1'
JE WTOBLACK
JNE LABAS

WTOBLACK:
CMP COUNTER,'1'
JE BLACK
CMP COUNTER,'2'
JE  BLUE
CMP COUNTER,'3'
JE  GREEN
CMP COUNTER,'4'
JE  CYAN
CMP COUNTER,'5'
JE  RED 
CMP COUNTER,'6'
JE  MAGENTA
CMP COUNTER,'7'
JE  YELLOW
CMP COUNTER,'8'
JE  WHITE
JMP TYPEAGAIN
LABAS:
JMP EXIT

BLACK  :
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00000000b
JMP LOC

BLUE   :
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00010001b
JMP LOC

GREEN  :
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00100010b
JMP LOC

CYAN   :
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00110011b
JMP LOC

RED    :
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11001100b
JMP LOC

MAGENTA:
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11011101b
JMP LOC

YELLOW:
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11101110b
JMP LOC

WHITE  :
MOV COUNTER,'0'
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11111111b
JMP LOC

LOC:
mov ch,0;start row
mov cl,0;start column
mov dh,5;end row
mov dl,25;end column
int 10h
JMP TYPEAGAIN

EXIT:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem more precisely.

Comment: No related but: comment your assembly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in my compiler, when labels and colons are separated, ex: `BLACK    :`, it's an error, it must be `BLACK:`.

Second, at the bottom of your code you are using `int 10h` with service `06H`, this means that you want to scroll a screen area. This interrupt need one parameter that your forgot : you have to store the number of rows to scroll in `al`. In your case, AL always contains '1', which is number 49, so your code is scrolling 49 rows the screen area. The number 6 would be more apropiate because you mentioned in your comment that you want to scroll rows 0 to 5. But, to make it more interesting, I will choose number 1 so it will look like a rainbow (you can choose any other number).

Oh yes, and I added some comments that are extremely important in assembly:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
mes db 'ENTER ANY NUMBER: $'
COUNTER DB '0'

.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

TYPEAGAIN:
mov ah,02H
MOV bh,00
mov dh,13
mov dl,35
int 10h               ;SET CURSOR POSITION.

mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset mes
int 21h               ;DISPLAY STRING.

mov ah,01h
int 21h               ;READ KEY.
INC COUNTER

CMP AL,'1'
JE WTOBLACK
JNE LABAS

WTOBLACK:
CMP COUNTER,'1'
JE BLACK
CMP COUNTER,'2'
JE  BLUE
CMP COUNTER,'3'
JE  GREEN
CMP COUNTER,'4'
JE  CYAN
CMP COUNTER,'5'
JE  RED 
CMP COUNTER,'6'
JE  MAGENTA
CMP COUNTER,'7'
JE  YELLOW
CMP COUNTER,'8'
JE  WHITE
JMP TYPEAGAIN
LABAS:
JMP EXIT

BLACK:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00000000b
JMP LOC

BLUE:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00010001b
JMP LOC

GREEN:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00100010b
JMP LOC

CYAN:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,00110011b
JMP LOC

RED:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11001100b
JMP LOC

MAGENTA:
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11011101b
JMP LOC

YELLOW:
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11101110b
JMP LOC

WHITE:                 ;FIXED LABEL.
MOV COUNTER,'0'
MOV AH,06H
mov bh,11111111b
JMP LOC

LOC:
mov al, 1             ;HOW MANY ROWS TO SCROLL.
mov ch,0;start row
mov cl,0;start column
mov dh,5;end row
mov dl,25;end column
int 10h               ;SCROLL DOWN SCREEN AREA.
JMP TYPEAGAIN

EXIT:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

Comment: @silaunospavlos:  a lookup table would be a lot simpler and better than this sequence of conditional branches to jump to different `mov reg, imm` instructions.